# Use type traits to detect whether an array (or a pointer) was passed

Tags: c++, templates, perfect-forwarding, forwarding-reference

I am trying to get a simple example to work to understand how to use `std::enable_if`, here is the problem:

I am reading the textbook C++ Templates The Complete Guide by David Vandevoorde, Nicolai M.Josuttis, Chapter 7, Section 4.

This chapter mentions: "You can use type traits to detect whether an array (or a pointer) was passed", and its following code:

```cpp
template<typename T,
         std::enable_if_t<std::is_array_v<T>>>
void foo(T&& arg1, T&& arg2)
{
    
}
```

My question is, how should the above code be called and used? for example, I tried:

```cpp
int x[] = {1, 2, 3};
int y[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
foo(x, y);
```

but didn't compile, i couldn't find similar usage online, can someone please give me some hints or code guidance on how to use above code?

Answer (score 2):

1. You should specify a default value for the 2nd template parameter, or move it to the return type.
2. With forwarding reference `T` might be deduced as lvalue-reference (when passed lvalues like `x` and `y`), which is not an array and yields `false` for `std::is_array`.
3. `x` is of type `int[3]`, `y` is of type `int[5]`. They're different types and causes the type deduction on `T` failing.

So

```
template<typename T,
         std::enable_if_t<std::is_array_v<std::remove_reference_t<T>>>* = nullptr>
void foo(T&& arg1, T&& arg2)
{ 
}
```

or

```
template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_array_v<std::remove_reference_t<T>>> foo(T&& arg1, T&& arg2)
{ 
}
```

then

```
int x[] = {1, 2, 3};
int y[] = {4, 5, 6};
foo(x, y);
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/AnVBuMaXqNGCtI4I)